# How to plot in-phase/Quadrant of the BPSK,QPSK and MSK after the modulation and after adding the noise?

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help me solving this question:

The task is to plot two diagrams that show the I/Q component for each modulation scheme : BPSK, QPSK, 16 QAM, and MSK for only ONE data set which will be after the modulation, and after adding the white Gaussian noise.

So what I would like to understand how can I plot those components using scatterplot() function after the modulation and after adding the noise.

This is the parts of the code that are related to the modulation and the white Gaussian noise:

```
%******************** BPSK Modulation ***********************
data1=data.*2-1;
data2] = oversamp( data1, nd , IPOINT);
data3 = conv(data2,xh);  % conv: built in function
```

and here after adding the noise :

```
%************ Add White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) ***************
inoise=randn(1,length(data3)).*attn;  % randn: built in function
data4=data3+inoise;
data5=conv(data4,xh2);  % conv: built in function
sampl=irfn*IPOINT+1;
data6 = data5(sampl:8:8*nd+sampl-1);
```

For the QPSK

```
 %************* QPSK Modulation ********************************  
[ich,qch]=qpskmod(data1,1,nd,ml);
[ich1,qch1]= compoversamp(ich,qch,length(ich),IPOINT);
[ich2,qch2]= compconv(ich1,qch1,xh);

%********************* Add White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) **********************

[ich3,qch3]= comb(ich2,qch2,attn);% add white gaussian noise
[ich4,qch4]= compconv(ich3,qch3,xh2);
syncpoint=irfn*IPOINT+1;
ich5=ich4(syncpoint:IPOINT:length(ich4));
qch5=qch4(syncpoint:IPOINT:length(qch4));
```

For the MSK

```
%*************************** MSK Modulation ********************************
[ich,qch]=qpskmod(data1,1,nd/2,2);
smooth1=cos(pi/2*[-1+1./4.*[0:IPOINT-1]]); %IPOINT point filtering
for ii=1:length(ich)
  ich2((ii-1)*IPOINT+1:ii*IPOINT)=(-1)^(ii-1)*smooth1.*ich(ii);
  qch2((ii-1)*IPOINT+1:ii*IPOINT)=(-1)^(ii-1)*smooth1.*qch(ii);
end
ich21=[ich2 zeros(1,IPOINT/2)];
qch21=[zeros(1,IPOINT/2) qch2];

%********************* Add White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) **********************
[ich3,qch3]= comb(ich21,qch21,attn);% add white gaussian noise
syncpoint=1;
ich5 = ich3(syncpoint+IPOINT/2:IPOINT:length(ich2));
qch5 = qch3(syncpoint+IPOINT:IPOINT:length(ich2)+IPOINT/2);
ich5(2:2:length(ich5))=-1*ich5(2:2:length(ich5));
qch5(2:2:length(ich5))=-1*qch5(2:2:length(ich5));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a "how to use matlab" question, not a DSP question - you'd be better asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a specialized function like `scatterplot`; you're making this more complicated than you have to. `scatterplot` is just a thin wrapper around `plot`. Remember that in order to plot a vector `y` versus a vector `x`, you just use `plot(x,y)`. So, for your various cases, all you need to do is `plot(I_data,Q_data)`.

Comment: Or `plot(I_data, Q_data, '.')` if the OP is looking for a constellation diagram.

Comment: Indeed; you would want to specify the dot symbol; the line-connected default plot style probably won't be meaningful.